# Select-query with connection to a subquery runs forever

Tags: mysql

For my [mysql-audit-tables project](https://github.com/myonara/mysql-audit) I want to compare the definitions of the original data table with the related audit table, which has the same columns plus some header information.

**EDIT:** after creating a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a32c65/6/0) for this issue, I found out on sqlfiddle (MYSQL V5.6) it is working, and in my 5.7 installation on windows I have different result for the third of the 3 queries (drop column).

**EDIT:** Added the example tables to compare with:

```
CREATE TABLE `audit_testdata`.`testtable` (-- the data table!
  `text_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text_type_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text_other_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text_lng_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text_access_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text_html` text,
  `text_plain` text,
  `testadd` varchar(42) DEFAULT NULL,-- new field to test queries!
  PRIMARY KEY (`text_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `text_id` (`text_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `audit`.`testtable_audit` ( -- audit table, simplified
  `audit_seq` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `audit_pk` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `audit_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `text_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'pk_testtable: ',-- change d field to test queries.
  `text_type_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text_other_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text_lng_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text_access_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text_html` text,
  `text_plain` text,
  `text_symbol` blob,-- deleted field to test queries.
  PRIMARY KEY (`audit_pk`),
  UNIQUE KEY `audit_pk` (`audit_pk`),
  KEY `text_id` (`text_id`),
  KEY `audit_timestamp` (`audit_timestamp`),
  KEY `audit_seq` (`audit_seq`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Some preparation views:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v_audit_info_tables;
CREATE VIEW v_audit_info_tables AS 
SELECT CONCAT('`',TABLE_SCHEMA,'`.`',TABLE_NAME,'`') AS FQ_TABLE_NAME,
       TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v_audit_info_columns;
CREATE VIEW v_audit_info_columns AS 
SELECT CONCAT('`',TABLE_SCHEMA,'`.`',TABLE_NAME,'`') AS FQ_TABLE_NAME,
       CONCAT('`',TABLE_SCHEMA,'`.`',TABLE_NAME,'`.`',COLUMN_NAME,'`') AS FQ_COLUMN_NAME,
       TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_TYPE,IS_NULLABLE,COLUMN_KEY,COLUMN_DEFAULT,
       CONCAT('`',COLUMN_NAME,'` ',
        UPPER(COLUMN_TYPE),
        IF(IS_NULLABLE='YES',' NULL ',' NOT NULL '),
        'COMMENT ''',REPLACE(COLUMN_COMMENT,'''',''''''),'''') AS FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS;
```

Here is a mapping view to link each data table with its audit table. In my real project there are configurations tables to use:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v_audit_map_tables;
CREATE VIEW v_audit_map_tables AS 
SELECT dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME AS dat_fq_table_name,dat.TABLE_SCHEMA AS dat_table_schema,dat.TABLE_NAME AS dat_table_name,
aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME AS aud_fq_table_name,aud.TABLE_SCHEMA AS aud_table_schema,aud.TABLE_NAME as aud_table_name
FROM v_audit_info_tables dat JOIN v_audit_info_tables  aud
ON aud.TABLE_NAME = CONCAT(dat.TABLE_NAME,'_audit') 
WHERE dat.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'audit_testdata' AND aud.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'audit';
;
```

For a complete picture is here the working query for modifying columns:

```
SELECT dat.FQ_COLUMN_NAME,dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE,AUD.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE,
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME,' MODIFY COLUMN `',dat.COLUMN_NAME,'` ',dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE) AS modify_cmd,
    dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME,aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME
FROM v_audit_info_columns dat JOIN v_audit_info_columns aud 
ON dat.COLUMN_NAME = aud.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE <> aud.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE
;
```

Here is the nonworking query, which seems to run forever:

```
SELECT dat.FQ_COLUMN_NAME,dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE,NULL,
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',audmap.aud_fq_table_name,' ADD COLUMN `',dat.COLUMN_NAME,'` ',dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE) AS modify_cmd,
    dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME,audmap.aud_fq_table_name
FROM v_audit_info_columns dat JOIN v_audit_map_tables audmap
ON audmap.dat_fq_table_name = dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME
WHERE dat.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT aud.COLUMN_NAME FROM v_audit_info_columns aud 
        WHERE aud.TABLE_NAME = audmap.aud_table_name AND aud.TABLE_SCHEMA = audmap.aud_table_schema
        -- AND aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME = audmap.aud_fq_table_name
    );
```

I tried first the `aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME = audmap.aud_fq_table_name` and the to adress the `TABLE_NAME/TABLE_SCHEMA` directly. I've looked in a bunch of other questions, so my new idea is to redesign the final query, but I have still no idea, how.

**EDIT-2:** Here is now the slow working solution, the queries above were slow AND wrong. The essential hint to get it working was in the [MYSQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html). I put the cases together in one UNION, which runs on my windows for about 6 seconds, so I'm still interested to optimize more:

```
SELECT dat.FQ_COLUMN_NAME,dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE AS dat_change,AUD.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE AS aud_change,
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME,' MODIFY COLUMN `',dat.COLUMN_NAME,'` ',dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE) AS modify_cmd,
    dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME AS dat_table_name,aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME AS aud_table_name
FROM v_audit_info_columns dat JOIN v_audit_info_columns aud 
ON dat.COLUMN_NAME = aud.COLUMN_NAME
JOIN v_audit_map_tables audmap 
ON dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME = audmap.dat_fq_table_name AND aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME = audmap.aud_fq_table_name
WHERE dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE <> aud.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE
UNION
SELECT dat.FQ_COLUMN_NAME,dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE,NULL,
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',audmap.aud_fq_table_name,' ADD COLUMN `',dat.COLUMN_NAME,'` ',dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE) AS modify_cmd,
    dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME,audmap.aud_fq_table_name
FROM v_audit_info_columns dat 
JOIN v_audit_map_tables audmap ON (audmap.dat_fq_table_name = dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM v_audit_info_columns aud WHERE dat.aud_fq_column_name = aud.FQ_COLUMN_NAME)
UNION
SELECT aud.FQ_COLUMN_NAME,NULL,aud.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE,
    CONCAT('-- ALTER TABLE ',aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME,' DROP COLUMN `',aud.COLUMN_NAME,'`') AS modify_cmd,
    audmap.dat_fq_table_name, audmap.aud_fq_table_name
 FROM v_audit_info_columns aud JOIN v_audit_map_tables audmap
ON audmap.aud_fq_table_name = aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM v_audit_info_columns dat 
    WHERE dat.fq_column_name = CONCAT(audmap.dat_fq_table_name,'.`',aud.COLUMN_NAME,'`'))
;
```

Comment: I've added `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('audit','audit_testdata');`to the first three views, which has enhanced the final query down to 2,5 seconds. Also I've used the new `FQ_COLUMN_NAME` to search in the subquery, There is an additional 0.016 to the 2.5, if I limit the subquery to the specified table. I'm still interested in a better solution, for my testing environment 2.5 is ok, but with multiple tables I expect a longer execution time...

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the union additionally two tables with indices are needed, from 6.14 seconds  to 0.063 seconds on my computer. Here are they:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS audit12_columns (
        FQ_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(133), 
        FQ_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY,
        TABLE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(64),
        TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(64), 
        COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(64), 
        FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE VARCHAR(2000), 
        aud_fq_column_name VARCHAR(200),
        INDEX (FQ_TABLE_NAME),
        UNIQUE KEY (TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME),
        UNIQUE KEY (aud_fq_column_name)
        );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS audit12_mapping (
        dat_fq_table_name VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY, 
        dat_table_schema VARCHAR(64), 
        dat_table_name VARCHAR(64), 
        aud_fq_table_name VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE, 
        aud_table_schema VARCHAR(64), 
        aud_table_name VARCHAR(64),
        UNIQUE KEY (dat_table_schema,dat_table_name),
        UNIQUE KEY (aud_table_schema,aud_table_name) 
        );
```

The tables can be filled by the corresponding views, and as it is done on a table by table basis, it is possible only to provide these data entries to the table:

```
DELETE FROM audit12_mapping;
    INSERT INTO audit12_mapping (dat_fq_table_name, dat_table_schema, dat_table_name, 
        aud_fq_table_name, aud_table_schema, aud_table_name)
    SELECT dat_fq_table_name, dat_table_schema, dat_table_name, 
        aud_fq_table_name, aud_table_schema, aud_table_name
        FROM v_audit_map_tables 
        WHERE dat_fq_table_name = i_id_data_table;-- limit to actual entry.

DELETE FROM audit12_columns;
    INSERT INTO audit12_columns (FQ_TABLE_NAME, FQ_COLUMN_NAME, 
        TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, 
        FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE, aud_fq_column_name)
    SELECT FQ_TABLE_NAME, FQ_COLUMN_NAME, 
        TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, 
        FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE, aud_fq_column_name
        FROM v_audit_info_columns
        WHERE (FQ_TABLE_NAME = i_id_data_table OR FQ_TABLE_NAME = l_id_audit_table);
```

And the final UNION-query looks like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME,' MODIFY COLUMN ',dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE,';') AS modify_cmd
        FROM audit12_columns dat JOIN audit12_columns aud 
        ON dat.COLUMN_NAME = aud.COLUMN_NAME
        JOIN audit12_mapping audmap 
        ON dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME = audmap.dat_fq_table_name AND aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME = audmap.aud_fq_table_name
        WHERE dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE <> aud.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE
    UNION
    SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',audmap.aud_fq_table_name,' ADD COLUMN ',dat.FQ_COLUMN_CHANGE,';') AS modify_cmd
        FROM audit12_columns dat 
        JOIN audit12_mapping audmap ON (audmap.dat_fq_table_name = dat.FQ_TABLE_NAME)
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM audit12_columns aud WHERE dat.aud_fq_column_name = aud.FQ_COLUMN_NAME)
    UNION
    SELECT CONCAT('-- ALTER TABLE ',aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME,' DROP COLUMN `',aud.COLUMN_NAME,'`;') AS modify_cmd
        FROM audit12_columns aud JOIN audit12_mapping audmap
        ON audmap.aud_fq_table_name = aud.FQ_TABLE_NAME
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM audit12_columns dat 
            WHERE dat.fq_column_name = CONCAT(audmap.dat_fq_table_name,'.`',aud.COLUMN_NAME,'`'))
    ;
```

By the way, I tried first to put audit12_columns and audit12_mapping as temporary tables, but there I run into the ERROR 1137: Can't reopen table: 'temp_table' error, which was explained in the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-table-problems.html).